# How to change the authentication type in SOAP UI 5.2.1?

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I am using the free version of **SOAP UI 5.2.1**. Unable to change the authentication type as shown in the image.

Operating system : El capitan 10.11.6

[image: Cannot change the authentication type]

Comment: Have you added that `HttpRequest` step under `TestCase`?

Comment: @PriyanshuShekhar I did not create any 'TestCase'. I just created a project from wsdl which gives me list of all the methods. For one specific method, I just wanted to add the "Basic Authentication".

Comment: Add that step in TestSuite->TestCase, you will be able to change Authentication Type. There will be a dropdown.

Answer (score 7):

I used SoapUI 5.2.1 and I faced the same problem and I found a solution on the [official page](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Can-t-change-request-authentication-type-in-SoapUI-5/td-p/40667). It states the following:

> Click on the "Auth" item in the bottomr right of your Request window. An additional section will appear on the Request window. Click on the "No Authentication" dropdown list and choose an authentication type to add.

In order to work in my case I also had to change the radio box from `Use global preference` to `Authenticate pre-emptively`

[image: Soap UI 5.2.1 screenshot to display authentication type modification]

Answer (score 0):

go to preferences > HTTP Settings > select "Authenticate Preemptively" check box
then you will see Auth tab in the request window.